# Android changing color with delay?

Tags: java, android, ondraw

Okay um so far I have been looking for some way to fix this issue and I've been at this for like already 5 days so I'm gonna try and explain it as best possible I have this app which works fine the only thing I'm struggling with is the color change of the ball. The thing is I want it to change like every 5 seconds, instead if it constantly changing randomly without waiting. For instance when the app opens the color of the ball in the app is red for like 5 seconds then after it changes to like blue and waits another 5 seconds before it changes to another color. I'm trying to figure out in code where the onDraw keeps randomly changing the color without waiting? I would really appreciate any help or advice cuz I have been at this for a while.

```
          @protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          ballBounds.set(ballX-ballRadius, ballY-ballRadius, ballX+ballRadius,ballY+ballRadius);
          Handler handler = new Handler();        
           int rnd = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
              switch(rnd){
    case 0:handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }, 3000);
        break;
    case 1: handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }, 3000);
        break;
    case 2: handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }, 3000);
        break;
    case 3:handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
            paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
        }, 3000);
        break;
        }
    canvas.drawOval(ballBounds, paint);

update();

try{
    Thread.sleep(20);
}catch(InterruptedException e){}

invalidate();
}
```

Comment: I would just make it all in one thread, get the delta time from one update to another and add it to an int. Everytime that int reaches 5 seconds or more, the ball toggles color and 5 seconds is subtracted from the int.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control how many times onDraw will be called, it's up to Android to decide it.

Instead you can run a separate thread which will change the value of the color every 5 seconds and let your `onDraw` use this value.

Answer (score 0):

OnDraw will be called multiple times per second in most cases.  It will do so at potential random time intervals depending in how your code is setup.

So your first call into draw could happen at time = 0ms, your second call could happen at 100ms, etc.  Therefore, you might get a blue for 100ms followed by a red until the next color change occurs.  You would need to restructure your handlers so that they are outside your draw mechanism most likely.

Perhaps invalidate your view for draw inside a single handler outside the onDraw method. Similar to something on the lines of this that would loop around and continuously update the view with a different color.  ***Warning, not tested, quick pseudo-code***.

```
public MyViewConstructorOrSimilarClass()
{
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override 
      public void run() 
      {
         int rnd = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
         switch(rnd)
         {
             case 0:
                globalpaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
             case 1:
                globalpaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                break;
             case 2:
                globalpaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
             case 3:
                globalpaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                break;
         }
         invalidate();//requestLayout(); Depends on view.
         handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
       }
    };
}

@protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    ballBounds.set(ballX-ballRadius, ballY-ballRadius, ballX+ballRadius,ballY+ballRadius);  
    canvas.drawOval(ballBounds, globalpaint);
}
```

Comment: alright I'll give this a shot just, curious what do you mean by requestLayout, I just extended View?

Comment: You can check up on these yourself for [requestLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()) and [invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate())